# Желтый дом

Tags: этимология

И еще один вопрос по "народной" этимологии. Сумасшедшие дома, насколько мне известно, еще называют "желтый дом". А почему желтый? Откуда пошло это выражение?
Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из словаря Михельсона :

> Большой толково-фразеологический словарь Михельсона
> **желтый дом**
> Ведь ты просто с ума сойдешь, в желтом доме жизнь кончишь.
> Достоевский. Село Степанчиково
> Снилось мне, что в Петрограде,
> Чрез Обухов мост пешком
> Перешел, спешу к ограде
> И вступаю в Желтый Дом.
> А.Ф. Воейков. Дом сумасшедших.
> Его в безумные упрятал дядя-плут;
> Схватили, в желтый дом, и на цепь посадили.
> Грибоедов. Горе от ума. 3, 16. Загорецкий о Чацком.
> Дом этот назван "желтым" — от желтой окраски (Обуховской больницы); потом "отправить в желтый дом" заменилось словами "отправить на тринадцатую версту" (по Петергофской дороге), куда был переведен дом для сумасшедших.